# Change selection style

Tags: microsoft-visio

Suddenly my selection tool style changet from usual rectangular to dotted line:

Rectangular:

[image]

Dotted line:

[image]

How to get back to rectangular selection?

Comment: Generally in any like tool (PDF, Excel, SnagIt and so on) I just delete the shape and add a rectangular shape. Faster.

Comment: how to do that in visio?

Comment: You need to look at the Visio Toolbar for shapes.

Comment: Here is the Microsoft Support article:  ...... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/draw-a-shape-in-visio-259ed0da-4444-4bf3-9093-33a0a79629e8

Comment: You seem to have changed the [Shape selection tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/shape-selection-tools-812c8f5a-e7c4-40ed-82f0-c796916878b3).